# Scala Lowest common Ancestor

Tags: scala, list

Assume below are directory structures in a list, how to find lowest common ancestor for these.

```
List(
("A/A1/A11/A111/a111.txt", "(M)"),
("A/A1/A11/A112/a112.txt", "(M)"),
("A/A1/A12/A121/",  "(D)")
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code that doesn't work and we can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function helped!!

```
def longestCommonParent(s1: String, s2: String): String = {
    val maxSize = scala.math.min(s1.length, s2.length)
    var i: Int = 0;
    while (i < maxSize && s1(i) == s2(i)) i += 1;
    parentFolder(s1.take(i));
  }

 def parentFolder(path: String) = {
    path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"))
  }
```